# How to tell a non-class method which child class a child object is?

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm not well versed with inheritance in python. I'm currently writing a set of child classes that inherit from a single parent class, e.g.,

```
class child1(parent):
  # define some stuff

class child2(parent):
  # define some stuff
```

There's a separate non-class function that takes in one of the child objects and depending on which child object it is, it does certain things, e.g.,

```
def function(child_object):
  if child_object is child1:
    # do something
  elif child_object is child2:
    # do something else
```

I am wondering if there's a native way in the polymorphism properties in Python to allow `function` to tell which child class `child_object` is? Currently, I have a string in the parent class that gets set to the name of the child class and that's how the distinction is made.

Comment: How about `isinstance(child_object, child1)`

Comment: You can also look at `@functools.singledispatch`

Comment: _I have a string in the parent class that gets set to the name of the child class_ - you can use `some_instance.__class__.__name__` if you need the class name as string. However there are better ways to deal with this, which **in my opinion looks very mutch like XY problem**.

Comment: I think this should be easy to do if each class implements what ever they need to do by them selfs in a method with the same name for each class, and the function only calls this method. (I hope my comment can be understand)

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte, in this case it is doubtful if they need a function at all, i.e. instead of passing instance to a function that only calls specific method (present in both child classes), they can simply call the method

Comment: @buran. Sure if it is such a simple case yes you do not need a function only a class is enough. But in a more complex case probably the function  call some method or attributes of the the class an uses the output to kepp working. In a function where they are using dependency inversion this (as is the case) should be the way of working. But in any case without knowing what they are trying is difficult to help more